# Weird CSRF error in Django with Nginx and Gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, csrf, gunicorn

**Background**

When I try to access into my Django administration panel, I get `Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.`, even if I disable the CSRF middleware. This affects all users, in different locations with different browsers. I've followed the steps to fix this error of several questions in stackoverflow, but still the same. This has been killing me for weeks.

**Issue**

I'm using https with Cloudflare (Free plan), but this error persist if I deactivate https. This occurs in `mydomain.com/admin`

**Known facts**

1. I'm using Django 2.0 and gunicorn 19.0
2. I've checked the cookies of my browser
3. I've tried removing `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware`
4. This occurs just in the Django Admin dashboard, when CSRF middleware is enabled, the another POST or GET forms works fine.
5. I'm logged into my Django Admin dashboard, and if I logout, I can login again with no problems, but if I try from another place, or with another user, the problem occurs again.
6. Gunicorn config it's the default.

**Configuration files**

Settings.py

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['.domain.com']
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ['.domain.com', '127.0.0.1']
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'domain.com', 'www.domain.com', '104.336.44.153', '.domain.com']

MIDDLEWARE = [
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Nginx

```
server {
    server_name domain.com;

    access_log off;

    location /static {
        alias /opt/myenv/myenv/static/;
    }

    location /descargas/dir/ {
        alias /opt/myenv/myenv/dir/;
    }



    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

Please help! Thanks for reading.

Comment: I think it's in the `securitymiddleware` instead of `csrfviewmiddleware`. Try to disable that.

Comment: Done, but the CSRF error persist.

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? Experiencing something similar now myself.

Comment: Found any solution for this? facing similar problem aswell..

Answer (score 0):

The CSRF cookie is set by `CsrfViewMiddleware`, so you should keep it.

I would try to change your `MIDDLEWARE` ordering:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', # THE FIRST
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: Now I've added the CSRF middleware again, my search forms in my principal page shows CSRF verification failed, I'm adding the csrf_token in the search input. Additionally, Admin Dashbord still showing the CSRF error.

Comment: Can you try to clean your browser cookies, then reload the page? If still the error persist, to make sure that the cookie is being set correctly, please check the request headers of your POST request (for example admin login) to ensure that it is also being sent (and matches the value of the CSRF token in the form)

Comment: The most likely scenario is that the cookie is not being set correctly, but not sure. Try eventually to comment `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN`.

Comment: Also, checking your settings, the `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` may cause issues when testing on local environment without SSL.