# CSRF verification always fails when accessing Django admin page through nginx proxy

Tags: django, nginx, django-admin, csrf, gunicorn

I have gunicorn serving a Django (v3.0.6) project on my server (at port 8000). I have the host name (and variations on localhost) in the ALLOWED_HOSTS variable of my Django project. And I have nginx set up to serve various apps within my Django project via a reverse proxy, like this:

```
        location /guestbook/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/guestbook/ ;
        }
```

These all seem to work just fine, for the record. What *isn't* working fine is the Django admin app. Initially I set it up with a very simple reverse proxy as shown above, but over time, as I was experiencing problems with it, I started incorporating various suggestions I found online  until now it looks like this:

```
        location /admin/ {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/admin/ ;
        }
```

but my problem persists: If I visit the admin site (via the nginx proxy) remotely after clearing all my cookies, the admin page loads just fine. I type in my login credentials, hit "login" and nothing happens. If I hit login again, the CSRF verification fails, and if I have DEBUG set to True Django says the CSRF verification failed because of an incorrect or missing CSRF token. If I look at my headers and cookies in Firefox and Chrome, I can see that there is a CSRF token, so it must be incorrect somehow. But I haven't yet figured out why. If, after this has failed, I again visit the admin app with my cookies intact, I get an empty HTTP 200 response and the browser displays nothing.

Interestingly, I have CSRF verification enabled on another app (my guestbook example above) and that passes just fine.

Any ideas as to why CSRF always fails specifically on the Django admin app and not on other parts of my Django project? Thanks.

**Edited to add**: I initially thought I remembered being able to log into the admin console by connecting directly to gunicorn via an SSH port forward. However, I think I must have been thinking of tests I did connecting to a local instance of my Django project running via gunicorn; when I connect directly to gunicorn running on my remote server via an ssh port forward I get the same behavior described above, so I think it might not have much to do with my Nginx configuration after all...

Comment: Hmm, so now that I've posted this, I'm finally finding more relevant questions out there that sound like the same problem I'm having, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853797/weird-csrf-error-in-django-with-nginx-and-gunicorn

So this might be a duplicate.

Comment: You say nothing happens the first time you hit "login". Can you see anything in the network tab on your browser?

Comment: @IainShelvington yes, at that point there's a 302 redirect (from /admin/login?next=/admin/  to /admin/).

Comment: Well, I've found a workaround. Not sure it counts as an answer. I simply started using Daphne to serve my Django project, instead of gunicorn. Now I have no issue with the admin site.